# Kivy Python | Text Input Color Bug

Tags: python, button, colors, kivy, kivymd

My text should looks like this:

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

This is the code (I don't know what it's doing all my text fields that I add looks like this):

```
        MDFloatLayout:
        size_hint_y: .3
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: rgba(148, 117, 255, 255)
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                radius: [10, 10, 0, 0]   

        MDFloatLayout:  
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .71}  
            size_hint: .9, .32
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: rgba(131, 69, 255, 255)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [6] 
            TextInput:
                id: city_name
                hint_text: "Enter City Name"  
                size_hint: 1, None
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5} 
                height: self.minimum_height
                multiline: False
                font_name: "Poppins-Bold"
                font_size: "20sp"
                hint_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                foreground_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                backround_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
                padding: 15
                cursor_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                cursor_width: "2sp"
```

[image]

Can someone help me resolve this minor but annoying bug?

Comment: Try changing `foreground_color` to a darker one like [0, 0, 0, 1] (black) or `background_color` to a lighter one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misspelling in your `kv`. Change:

```
backround_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
```

to:

```
background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
```

Or set `background_color` to the desired background color of the `TextInput`.

Answer (score 0):

first things first

`background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0`

means the opacity of the color you are trying to set is 0. which means it is probably clear and transparent.

`background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1`

here the opacity is 1 but the first 3 numbers determine the color and the first 3 colors `1, 1, 1` means it is white.

The proper color for purple would probably be 128,0,128

`background_color: 128/255, 0, 128/255, 1`